# How to properly pass data from one page to another (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a conference details page and a page to register in conference. In the conference details page the user selects how many registrations want from each registration type of the conference and then click in the button "Next" to go to the registration page. My doubt is how to pass data from conference details page to the registration page? Because in the registration page is necessary to show a summary of the quantity of registration selected by the user in the conference details page.

The structure I have is:

I have a FrontEndController that has a show method to show the  conference details page:

```
public function show($id, $slug){
        $conf = Conference::where('id', $id)->first();
        $registrationTypes = RegistrationType::where('conf_id', $conf->id)->get();
        return view('confs.show')->with('conf',$conf)->with('registration_types', $registrationTypes);
    }
```

The route for this method above:

```
Route::get('/conference/{id}/{slug?}', [
    'uses' => 'FrontEndController@show',
    'as'   =>'confeerences.show'
]);
```

In the conference details page, when a user accesses "http://proj.test/conference/1/test-conference" the user can select how many registrations wants to acquire. For example if the conference has 2 registration types (rt01 and rt02) the user can select that he wants 2 of registration type "rt01" and 2 registrations from regitration type "rt02". For this there is this code below with select menu in the conference details view that allows the user to select the quantity of each registration type:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
        <span>Registration</span>
        <span>Quantity</span>
        <span>Price</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card_body">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            @foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                    <div class="w-100 text-truncate">
                        <span>{{$rtype->name}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <form>
                        <select class="custom-select form-control rtype_name"
                                 id="rtype_{{ $rtype->id }}" data-price="{{ $rtype->price }}" name={{ $rtype->name }}>
                            <option selected></option>
                        @for ($i = $rtype->min_participants; $i <= $rtype-> max_participants; $i++)
                                <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
                            @endfor
                        </select>
                </form>
                <span class="font-size-sm w-50 text-right">X {{$rtype->price}}€</span>
                </li>
            @endforeach
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <div>
                    <span>TOTAL</span>
                </div>
                <span class="total">0.00€</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <a  href="{{route('conferences.registration', ['id' => $conf->id, 'slug' => $conf->slug])}}">Next</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

After the user selects the number of registrations for each registration type that he wants he can click next to go to the registration page.

So I created this route:

```
Route::get('/conference/{id}/{slug?}/registration', [
    'uses' => 'FrontEndController@registration',
    'as'   =>'conferences.registration'
]);
```

And in FrontEndController I have the method:

```
public function registration(){
        return view('conferences.registration');
    }
```

And he goes to a registration page, in this page its necessary to show a summary like:

```
registration_types       quantity             price          subtotal
rt01                        2                   5.00$           10.00$    
rt02                        1                   10.00$          10.00$                 
TOTAL                                                           20.00$
```

I have this static for now in registration.blade.php file:

```
 <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
        <span>Summary</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card_body">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-registration d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <span>Registration Type</span>
                <span>Quantity</span>
                <span>Price</span>
                <span>Subtotal</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-registration d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <span>rt01</span>
                <span>2</span>
                <span>5.00$</span>
                <span>10.00$</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-registration d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <span>rt02</span>
                <span>1</span>
                <span>10.00$</span>
                <span>10.00$</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-registration d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <span>TOTAL</span>
                <span>20.00€</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Doubt:**

My doubt is how to pass the necessary information from the conference details view to the registration view, so its possible to show the summary like above but with dynamic data. Maybe I could have in the FrontEndController something like:

```
public function registration($id, $slug){
        $conf = Conference::where('id', $id)->first();
        $registrationTypes = RegistrationType::where('conf_id', $conf->id)->get();
        return view('confs.show')->with('conf',$conf)->with('registration_types', $registrationTypes);
        return view('confs.registration')->with('conf',$conf)->with('registration_types', $registrationTypes);

    }
```

But I already did this for the conference details page, is not possible to pass the information from the conference details page to the registration view without query again the database? And also with the method above the selected quantities are not possible to pass to the registration view, because they are not on the database. Do you know how can be possible to pass data from the conference details view to the registration view properly?

Comment: For this you need to understand the stateless nature of the internet, each request is done indecently, so you have to pass the data or store it somewhere.  Options, in the URL (GET)  as POST data,  Save it in the Database,  Save it in the session.  Which one depends on how long the data needs to live for, I would use the GET if is transient, POST if I need to process it, Session if I don't want the user to see it and need it later (such as 2 or three requests down the road), or the DB if its something I need between logins.

Comment: For this it sounds like it might be enaugh to add it to the query string of the url.  for the query string you can use `http_build_query()` and just tack it on to the other url.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php  Typically I only use post when I need to process something and modify data that I keep somewhere, but it's an option if you don't want it seen, but the easy way to do that is with a form submission,

Comment: If it's database stuff you don't want to show the end user, then stick it in the session `$_SESSION`

Comment: Thanks, but so on the conference details page when the user clicks in the link "<a  href="{{route('conferences.registration', ['id' => $conf->id, 'slug' => $conf->slug])}}">Next</a>
" to go to the registration page where the necessary info should be stored in the session? In the registration method of the FrontEndController?